# How do I convert an int 0-7 to a char 'a'-'h'?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert a number 0-7 into a letter 'a'-'h' for a text-based chess game for blind players. What I'm trying isn't working. Why is this?
Note: code shown below comes from multiple classes. Index is used when creating an array.

```
void Board::setPieceAtPosition(int index, Piece &piece)
{
   piece.setRow(index / 8);
   piece.setCol(index % 8);
}

char Piece::convertColToLetter()
{
   char letter = col + 49;
   return letter;
}

void Piece::display()
{
   char colLetter = convertColToLetter();
   int row = this->row + 1;
   if (isWhite)
   {
      std::cout << "White ";
   }
   else
   {
      std::cout << "Black ";
   }
   std::cout << name << " at " << colLetter << row << std::endl;
```

}

Comment: 49 is the ascii code for character '1'. Go look at the ascii table and figure out what the correct value should be.

Comment: Don't describe your code in English, post it.

Comment: I would have, but I have several relevant functions in different files, so I thought describing it was simpler.

Comment: This is one of the many places where producing a good [mcve] comes in handy. Done right you only need one example to handle all of the similar cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `char colLeter = col + 49` does not work

This is because `49` is not the code of letter `a`, it's the code of digit `1`.

Do not use numeric values for character codes. Use char literals instead. Char literals are characters enclosed in single quotes, e.g. `'a'`, `'b'`, `'0'`, etc.

Since `char` constants are actually numbers, you can add an `int` to them:

```
int pos = 4;
char c = 'a' + pos;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int col = ...; // 0-7

char colLetter = 'a' + col;
```

I think that `a`-`z` are guaranteed by the standard to have contiguous code points. Anyway, even if they aren't by standard, they are in ASCII.

So if for you `0` is `a`, `1` is `b` and so on, all you have to do is add the `col` to `a`.

Also please note that the types are important. `colLetter` must be `char`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int pos = 2; // 0->7
const char* column = "abcdefgh";

char colLetter = column[pos];
```

I find this way to be a lot nicer than the proposed type conversion between ints and chars. Obviously remember to do boundary checks when implementing.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks, been a long time since I've written c++